# How to convert from csv to nested json dictionary ( A beginner )

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My RESULTS:

```json
[
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "JOHN",
        "PRY SCHOOL": "OLIVETTE",
        "HIGH SCHOOL": "BAPTIST",
        "VEHICLEMAKE ": "TOYOTA",
        "VEHICLE COL": "BLACK",
        "TV MAKE": "SAMSUNG"
    },
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "KOFI",
        "PRY SCHOOL": "ACADAMY", 
        "HIGH SCHOOL": "MAYFLOWER",
        "VEHICLEMAKE ": "HONDA",
        "VEHICLE COL": "YELLOW",
        "TV MAKE": "TECHWOOD"
    },
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "BISI",
        "PRY SCHOOL": "IGBOBI",
        "HIGH SCHOOL": "ANGUS",
        "VEHICLEMAKE ": "HYUNDAI",
        "VEHICLE COL": "BLUE",
        "TV MAKE": "THERMOC"
    }
]
```

Intended results:

```json
[
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "JOHN",
        "SCHOOL": {
            "primary": "OLIVETTE",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "BAPTIST"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "TOYOTA",
            "COL": "BLACK"
        },
        "TV MAKE": "SAMSUNG"
    },
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "KOFI",
        "SCHOOL": {
            "primary": "ACADAMY",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "MAYFLOWER"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "HONDA",
            "COL": "YELLOW"
        },
        "TV MAKE": "TECHWOOD"
    },
    {
        "FIRST NAME": "BISI",
        "SCHOOL": {
            "primary": "IGBOBI",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "ANGUS"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "HYUNDAI",
            "COL": "BLUE"
        },
        "TV MAKE": "THERMO"
    }
]
```

My code :

```py
import csv
import json

filenames = 'csvfilepath.csv'
my_dic = []

with open(filenames, encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

     for row in csv_reader:
         my_dic.append(row)

with open('jasonfilepath.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    json.dump(my_dic, file_object ,indent = 4)
```

My data:

```
firstname  PRY SCHOOL HIGH SCHOOL VEHICLEMAKE VEHICLECOL  TVMAKE
JOHN       OLIVETTE   BAPTIST     TOYOTA      BLACK       SAMSUNG
KOFI       ACADAMY    MAYFLOWER    HONDA      YELLOW      TECHWOOD
BISI       IGBOBI     ANGUS        HYUNDAI    BLUE         THERMO
```

NB: the rows are more than 1000 rows

I want to ensure a nested structure in school (comprising primary and secondary) and vehicle(make and colour)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Is your input CSV data file tab separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) can't read nested data, you need to construct dictionary with required structure manually. For this case I'd use simple [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

**Code:**

```py
import csv
import json

with open(r"csvfilepath.csv", newline="") as inp_f, \
        open(r"jsonfilepath.json", "w") as out_f:
    reader = csv.reader(inp_f, delimiter="\t")
    next(reader)  # skip header
    my_dic = []
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) >= 6:  # skip rows which missing columns
            my_dic.append({
                "FIRST NAME": row[0],
                "SCHOOL": {
                    "primary": row[1],
                    "HIGH SCHOOL": row[2]
                },
                "VEHICLE": {
                    "MAKE": row[3],
                    "COL": row[4]
                },
                "TV MAKE": row[5]
            })
    if my_dic:  # if my_dic is not empty
        json.dump(my_dic, out_f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Please can i have an explanation why this code will not work when len(row)>=6 is removed I tried to remove it and the code failed. I need the explanation so as to better understand what is happening.

Comment: @AbdRaheem, it checks if there's at least 6 columns in row.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below (Are you sure about 'TV MAKE' location ?)

```
import json
data = [ { "FIRST NAME": "JOHN", "PRY SCHOOL": "OLIVETTE", "HIGH SCHOOL": "BAPTIST", "VEHICLEMAKE ": "TOYOTA", "VEHICLE COL": "BLACK", "TV MAKE": "SAMSUNG" }, { "FIRST NAME": "KOFI", "PRY SCHOOL": "ACADAMY", "HIGH SCHOOL": "MAYFLOWER", "VEHICLEMAKE ": "HONDA", "VEHICLE COL": "YELLOW", "TV MAKE": "TECHWOOD" }, { "FIRST NAME": "BISI", "PRY SCHOOL": "IGBOBI", "HIGH SCHOOL": "ANGUS", "VEHICLEMAKE ": "HYUNDAI", "VEHICLE COL": "BLUE", "TV MAKE": "THERMOC" } ]


new = [{'SCHOOL':{'PRIMARY':d['PRY SCHOOL'],'HIGH SCHOOL':d['HIGH SCHOOL']},'VEHICLE':{'MAKE':d['VEHICLEMAKE '],'COL':d['VEHICLE COL']},'FIRST NAME':d['FIRST NAME'],'TV MAKE':d['TV MAKE']} for d in data]

print(json.dumps(new,indent=4))
```

output

```
[
    {
        "SCHOOL": {
            "PRIMARY": "OLIVETTE",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "BAPTIST"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "TOYOTA",
            "COL": "BLACK"
        },
        "FIRST NAME": "JOHN",
        "TV MAKE": "SAMSUNG"
    },
    {
        "SCHOOL": {
            "PRIMARY": "ACADAMY",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "MAYFLOWER"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "HONDA",
            "COL": "YELLOW"
        },
        "FIRST NAME": "KOFI",
        "TV MAKE": "TECHWOOD"
    },
    {
        "SCHOOL": {
            "PRIMARY": "IGBOBI",
            "HIGH SCHOOL": "ANGUS"
        },
        "VEHICLE": {
            "MAKE": "HYUNDAI",
            "COL": "BLUE"
        },
        "FIRST NAME": "BISI",
        "TV MAKE": "THERMOC"
    }
]
```

Comment: NO thank you. I have edited my question . I want to have a nested structure at school (comprising primary and secondary) and vehicle ( comprising vehicle make and color)   The rows are more than 1000 rows , So we cant use the method above .

Comment: TV make and  first name are not nested.

Comment: @AbdRaheem Look at the output. This is the exact output you are looking for. Can you explain what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tab separated input file, you can construct the nesting as you read the input file by slightly modifying your logic:

```
with open(filenames, encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter="\t")
     for row in csv_reader:
         my_dic.append({"FIRST NAME": row['firstname'],
                        "SCHOOL" : { "PRIMARY": row['PRY SCHOOL'],
                                     "HIGH SCHOOL" : row['HIGH SCHOOL']},
                        "VEHICLE" : { "MAKE": row['VEHICLEMAKE'],
                                      "COL": row['VEHICLECOL']},
                        "TV MAKE" : row["TVMAKE"]})
```